# Simulating ground cancelling output stage in LTspice

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, single-supply-op-amp

I've tried to simulate ground cancelling mentioned by Douglas [here](http://www.douglas-self.com/ampins/balanced/balanced.htm):

[image: Ground cancelling arrangement]

The simulation cannot cancel ground noise:

1. V3 is noise pollution, V2 is microphone signal generator, V1 main power.
2. R8,R10,R9,C1 and C2 are part of cable.

[image: noise cancelling in LTspice]

+In low frequency noise should be cancelled after connecting the gap behind the AD8605, but even connecting that does not make a change in the simulations.

The .asc file:

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 1012 680
WIRE -368 144 -368 128
WIRE -336 144 -368 144
WIRE -256 144 -256 128
WIRE -32 144 -48 144
WIRE 448 176 400 176
WIRE 512 176 448 176
WIRE 576 176 512 176
WIRE -32 192 -32 144
WIRE -32 192 -160 192
WIRE 0 192 -32 192
WIRE 192 192 0 192
WIRE 224 192 192 192
WIRE 320 192 304 192
WIRE 400 192 400 176
WIRE 400 192 320 192
WIRE -592 224 -640 224
WIRE -512 224 -592 224
WIRE -368 224 -368 144
WIRE -368 224 -432 224
WIRE -640 240 -640 224
WIRE -368 240 -368 224
WIRE -336 240 -368 240
WIRE -256 256 -256 144
WIRE -256 256 -272 256
WIRE -112 256 -256 256
WIRE 0 256 -32 256
WIRE 192 256 0 256
WIRE 224 256 192 256
WIRE 320 256 304 256
WIRE 448 256 320 256
WIRE 512 256 448 256
WIRE -336 272 -368 272
WIRE 576 272 576 176
WIRE 688 272 576 272
WIRE -160 320 -160 192
WIRE -160 320 -208 320
WIRE 240 320 64 320
WIRE 464 320 320 320
WIRE 576 320 576 272
WIRE 576 320 464 320
WIRE -640 352 -640 320
WIRE -368 400 -368 272
WIRE -368 400 -432 400
WIRE -304 400 -368 400
WIRE -224 400 -224 320
FLAG -880 208 +
FLAG -304 224 +
FLAG 688 352 0
FLAG 64 320 MicGnd
FLAG -128 144 mgnd
FLAG 448 256 +In
FLAG 0 256 +Out
FLAG 0 192 -Out
FLAG 448 176 -In
FLAG -592 224 Mic
FLAG 464 320 Noisy_gnd
FLAG -304 288 MicGnd
FLAG -512 400 MicGnd
FLAG -640 352 MicGnd
FLAG -880 288 MicGnd
SYMBOL res -416 208 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 1k
SYMBOL res -240 128 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 1k
SYMBOL res -416 384 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 1k
SYMBOL res -208 384 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R4
SYMATTR Value 1k
SYMBOL voltage -880 192 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value 5
SYMBOL voltage -640 336 R180
WINDOW 3 -3 103 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value SINE(0.51 0.5 400)
SYMBOL OpAmps\\AD8605 -304 192 R0
SYMATTR InstName U1
SYMBOL res -16 240 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R5
SYMATTR Value 100
SYMBOL res -32 128 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R6
SYMATTR Value 100
SYMBOL cap 176 192 R0
WINDOW 0 24 17 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -62 29 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 0.5n
SYMBOL res 496 160 R0
SYMATTR InstName R7
SYMATTR Value 5k
SYMBOL res 336 304 R90
WINDOW 0 44 110 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 -24 65 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R8
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL res 320 176 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 -50 60 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R9
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL cap 304 192 R0
WINDOW 3 41 31 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName C2
SYMATTR Value 0.5n
SYMBOL voltage 688 256 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V3
SYMATTR Value SINE(0.1 0.1 50)
SYMBOL res 320 240 R90
WINDOW 0 44 102 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 -20 62 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R10
SYMATTR Value 1
TEXT -866 76 Left 2 !.tran 0 0.1 0 10m
TEXT -856 104 Left 2 !.option plotwinsize=0
TEXT -864 136 Left 2 !.option numdgt=7
```

Comment: The node `MicGnd` is floating. In SPICE, there is only one ground, a reference node, which sets the reference for all voltages, in order for the engine to be able to solve them. While a node, even ground, is only a label, the `0`, or `gnd` label are special. You can reference any voltage to any other node, such as `MicGnd` here, but that referenced node needs a reference to ground, somewhere. So, if you intend on making it floating, add a `1meg` resistor to ground from `MicGnd`, otherwise add a `1m` (virtual short). Or simply discard it and use the normal ground. Also, `R4` seems interrupted.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is the electronic equivalent of a typographic mistake. The circuit in Pass’s book works as shown, and a quick CircuitLab session confirms that.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Micgnd is connected to node 0 via R8 and V3. V3 has zero impedance, since it’s an ideal voltage source.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Yes.

Answer (score 5):

This is a nice circuit idea:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxhJqm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It appears to work as is.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The GC (Ground Cancelling) goal is to cancel ground noise generated (maybe in sensor(microphone)). In your simulation noise exists on Vout, we can see it as low frequency variation. Does it relate to GC? GC is implemented on 3 wire XLR connection, mentioned by self douglas in his book small signal audio.

Comment: You answer got 4 upvote maybe I can't understand it! Could you please also explain it to me?

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd The article that you linked in your question (by "Douglas") nicely explains its function and purpose. The problem is: If you have a single-ended receiver you run the risk of ground loop noise. If you add differential signaling, you usually also need a differential receiver. But if you cannot change the receiver (because it is part of a PC or such), this circuit will still make differential signalling work. It senses the Receiver ground noise with the second wire and adds it to the signal. The receiver then sees a perfect single-ended signal.

Comment: geound noise added to the signal but in your circuit why output is still have noise component, doesn't it?

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd yes this is the whole point! You add this noise deliberately, so the noisy receiver sees a noisefree signal (orange trace in bottom graph)

Comment: I've catched it, your answer is right. But I wonder why cable have 2 wire instead of 3. And why cable noise doesn't appear? I think your answer is insightful though, thanks for your patience. (up)

Answer (score -1):

I have found from "small signal audio" book a better circuit for single supply circuits (It must be non-inverting). And now the circuit is working:

[image: GND cancellation Simulation]

I have no idea how it really cancels the ground. Note by disconnecting -Out the signal will degrade by including low frequency component.

LTspice .asc:

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 1012 680
WIRE -336 64 -368 64
WIRE -256 64 -272 64
WIRE -368 144 -368 64
WIRE -336 144 -368 144
WIRE -256 144 -256 64
WIRE -32 144 -48 144
WIRE 448 176 400 176
WIRE 512 176 448 176
WIRE 576 176 512 176
WIRE -32 192 -32 144
WIRE -32 192 -160 192
WIRE 0 192 -32 192
WIRE 224 192 0 192
WIRE 400 192 400 176
WIRE 400 192 304 192
WIRE -592 224 -640 224
WIRE -576 224 -592 224
WIRE -512 224 -512 160
WIRE -400 224 -432 224
WIRE -368 224 -368 144
WIRE -368 224 -400 224
WIRE -640 240 -640 224
WIRE -368 240 -368 224
WIRE -336 240 -368 240
WIRE -256 256 -256 144
WIRE -256 256 -272 256
WIRE -208 256 -256 256
WIRE -112 256 -208 256
WIRE 0 256 -32 256
WIRE 224 256 0 256
WIRE 448 256 304 256
WIRE 512 256 448 256
WIRE -336 272 -368 272
WIRE 576 272 576 176
WIRE 640 272 576 272
WIRE -160 320 -160 192
WIRE -160 320 -224 320
WIRE 16 320 -64 320
WIRE 240 320 16 320
WIRE 448 320 320 320
WIRE 576 320 576 272
WIRE 576 320 448 320
WIRE -576 336 -576 224
WIRE -512 336 -576 336
WIRE -400 336 -432 336
WIRE -368 336 -368 272
WIRE -368 336 -400 336
WIRE -640 352 -640 320
WIRE 640 352 640 272
WIRE -368 400 -368 336
WIRE -304 400 -368 400
WIRE -224 400 -224 320
WIRE -400 464 -400 432
WIRE -400 480 -400 464
WIRE -224 480 -400 480
WIRE -64 480 -64 320
WIRE -64 480 -144 480
FLAG -816 240 +
FLAG -304 224 +
FLAG 640 352 0
FLAG 448 256 +In
FLAG 0 256 +Out
FLAG 0 192 -Out
FLAG 448 176 -In
FLAG -592 224 Mic
FLAG -304 288 MicGnd
FLAG -640 352 MicGnd
FLAG -816 320 MicGnd
FLAG -128 144 MicGnd
FLAG -512 160 MicGnd
FLAG 448 320 InGnd
FLAG 16 320 OutGnd
FLAG -400 464 MicGnd
FLAG -400 224 In1
FLAG -400 336 In2
FLAG -208 256 Out
SYMBOL res -416 208 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 4.7k
SYMBOL res -240 128 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL res -416 320 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 4.7k
SYMBOL res -208 384 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R4
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL voltage -816 224 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value 5
SYMBOL voltage -640 224 R0
WINDOW 3 -57 -9 VRight 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR Value SINE(1 0.5 400)
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMBOL OpAmps\\AD8605 -304 192 R0
SYMATTR InstName U1
SYMBOL res -16 240 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R5
SYMATTR Value 100
SYMBOL res -32 128 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R6
SYMATTR Value 100
SYMBOL res 496 160 R0
SYMATTR InstName R7
SYMATTR Value 5k
SYMBOL res 336 304 R90
WINDOW 0 44 110 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 -24 65 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R8
SYMATTR Value 10
SYMBOL res 320 176 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 -50 60 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R9
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL res 320 240 R90
WINDOW 0 44 102 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 -20 62 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R10
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL cap -272 48 R90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName C3
SYMATTR Value 47p
SYMBOL voltage -240 480 R270
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 0 54 52 VRight 2
WINDOW 3 30 301 VLeft 2
SYMATTR InstName V4
SYMATTR Value SINE(0.1 0.5 50)
TEXT -864 80 Left 2 !.tran 0 0.1 0 10m
TEXT -864 104 Left 2 !.option plotwinsize=0
TEXT -864 128 Left 2 !.option numdgt=7
```

Comment: I have no idea what you’re trying to answer here. You’ve draw exactly the circuit from the book picture you’ve shown. The mistakes in your spice model are of the “typo” kind, ie. not useful to anyone else.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Partially, yes. But my question still remains. How this circuit actually work. According to signal chain depicted in the simulation, how the low frequency component being cancelled?